# How to Find out where it Is made Breadcrumb Array in Magento 2.3.1

Tags: product-view, magento2.3.1, breadcrumbs, array

**where it Is made Breadcrumb Array in Magento 2.3.1?**

*In Detail page has show Breadcrumb but i m not able to find where it Is made Breadcrumb Array*

[image]

Can somebody help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For product page breadcrumbs loading from

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/web/js/product/breadcrumbs.js

function _resolveCategoryUrl

Basically the code is checking if category path included in url then its creating breadcrumbs path from url, otherwise it will check for referral url and if referral is category url then it will find category title and url from menu dropdown

See function _resolveCategoryCrumbs

So if category is not included in menu then it won't show breadcrumbs!

Answer (score 1):

for product page, 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/breadcrumbs.phtml

it is calling below js file
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/web/js/product/breadcrumbs.js

and it is creating json from below file
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/ViewModel/Product/Breadcrumbs.php#L104

hope it will clear your doubts.

Comment: i know that but how to made Array and where?

Comment: updated answer @SavanPatel

Comment: i know all three file you said me but how it work to create a array?

Comment: it is passing json into js file and js file do process, you just need to debug that js file

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few places.
Breadcrumbs are used almost identical as they were in Magento 1.

The module responsible with them is: Magento_Theme.
They are added to the layout in:

> vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

Block:

> vendor/magento/module-theme/Block/Html/Breadcrumbs.php

Template:

> vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/breadcrumbs.phtml

Now, each module that renders pages, can modify/add what breadcrumbs they want.

As I can see, you are interested in product page.
That is rendered "_prepareLayout()" from:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Breadcrumbs.php

If you want to find them all, just search all the magento vendor module for:

> ->addCrumb(